# How to update a single package without an (immediate) restart of the process

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, openvpn

How can I update a single package (here: openvpn) without an immediate restart of the process?

I want to update now and (at some better time i.e. during the night) restart the openvpn process.

Comment: In the past there was on Debian [`policy-rc.d`](https://people.debian.org/~hmh/invokerc.d-policyrc.d-specification.txt) with return code 101 to address this case. Now I don't know how it's working with systemd.